# Good number theory book

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for good number theory for math olympiad and I am asking because I already tried some.

I am looking for the book with many examples, methods and problems and (if its possible) with no academic style of teaching (for example the book doesn't include complex numbers and other things which are quite rare for solving number theory and algebra problems in math olympiad.

I was thinking about the

"Intruduction to number theory"

Mathew Crawford's book, can anyone describe on what level is this book, does it have many problems in it etc. or give any other
suggestion?

(My math level is much much less than IMO, I am trying to get into final in my country in math olympiad, but I have participated into second round of math olympiad and I train alot)

Comment: Perhaps you rather need olympiad books which have a chapter on number theory. This would be much more efficient. But anyway, your question has been answered, see for example [here](https://www.quora.com/Which-books-did-you-use-for-number-theory-from-the-basic-level-to-the-IMO-level).

Comment: Form the link - good number theory books for Maths Olympiads are
1. Number theory - Titu Andreescu and Dorin Andrica*
2. 104 Number theory problems - Titu Andreescu*
3. An introduction to diophantine equation - Titu Andreescu*
4. Mathematical Olympiad Challenges - Titu Andreescu*
5. An Excursion in Mathematics - Dr. V. V. Acharya*
6. Problem Primer for the Olympiad - B J Venkatachala, C R Pranesachar, C S Yogananda*
7. India and International Mathematical Olympiads - Rajeev Manocha*
8. Challenges and Thrills of Pre-College Mathematics
9. Past IMO and INMO papers and solutions*